# Unable to populate nested schema reference in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, backend, mongoose-schema

I have multiple Schemas and I'm trying to query the data using populate. I'm using mongoose(5.9.7) and express js.

First Schema - ProfileSchema

```
const ProfileSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  },
  jobs: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Job"
    }
  ],
  resumes: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Resume"
    }
  ],
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },

});

module.exports = Profile = mongoose.model("Profile", ProfileSchema);
```

Second Schema - Resume Schema

```
const ResumeSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  },
  fileLink: { type: String, required: true },
  fileName: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: true }
});

module.exports = Resume = mongoose.model("Resume", ResumeSchema);
```

Route

```
router.get(
  "/",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const profile = await Profile.findOne({
        user: req.user.id
      })
        .populate("resumes")
        .exec();
      res.json(profile);
    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(400).json(error);
    }
  }
);
```

This returns an empty array for both resume and jobs. I have tried different variations of populate but it doesn't work. Tried deeppopulate as well. Though User gets populated fine.

EDIT: Adding resume upload route

Route

```
router.post(
  "/upload",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  upload.single("resume"),
  async (req, res) => {
    try {
    // upload to s3 code here

      if (data) {
        const resumeData = {
          description: req.body.description,
          fileName: params.Key,
          fileLink: data.Location,
          user: req.user.id
        };

        const resume = new Resume(resumeData);
        const fileSavedToSchema = await resume.save();
        return res.json(fileSavedToSchema);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
);
```

I'm able to view the resumes using a different route.

Comment: Where do you write your resume references into the `resumes` array of the corresponding users? I don't see that here. (It doesn't happen automatically...) Also, check in your database directly what is saved inside the users... (using the mongo shell or a tool like MongoDB Compass or Robo 3T)

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I was not pushing the data to the profile schema. changing the code made it work. How do you suggest I can delete a resume ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61297292/how-do-i-delete-an-item-from-a-schema-which-is-an-array-of-objects-in-mongoose