# How do I delete an item from a Schema which is an array of objects in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, backend, mongoose-schema

I want to delete a resume from list of resumes in my schema.

I'm using mongoose(5.9.7) and express js.

Schema

```
const ResumeSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  },
  fileLink: { type: String, required: true },
  fileName: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: true }
});

module.exports = Resume = mongoose.model("Resume", ResumeSchema);
```

I have a route to fetch all the resumes.

I'm creating a ref of resume in my ProfileSchema as well.

Profile Schema

```
const ProfileSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  },
  resumes: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Resume"
    }
  ],
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },

});

module.exports = Profile = mongoose.model("Profile", ProfileSchema);
```

I don't know how to get ahead with delete. I couldn't make the update or pull work as they all seem to work for an array inside an object schemas.

Comment: do you want to send a delete request from postman or you want to create a button on the client and delete a resume upon clicking the button?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `remove` is the instance of the resume that you want to delete (which you got using `await Resume.findById(resumeId)`):

1) Delete the reference: you can do an `update` with [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) (the value to pull would be the resume's `_id`):

```js
// Assuming that `resume.user` is *not* populated
await User.update({ _id: resume.user }, { $pull: { resumes: resume._id } })
```

..or get the user, remove the corresponding entry in `resumes`, save the user.

2) Delete the resume using a simple `remove`:

```js
await resume.remove()
```

Comment: remove is deprecated I guess.

I was able to use findByIdAndRemove(id) to remove the item.

Comment: `Model.remove` (e.g. `Resume.remove({ _id: resumeId })`) is deprecated, `Model.prototype.remove` (e.g. `resume.remove()` like I did here) is not.